# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator ESB: Is there a way to Iterate N number of times

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a requirement to get data from a service, which is spanned over multiple pages.
Let the number of pages be called as N.

Is there a way to iterate N number of times or till a condition is met in WSO ESB and call a sequence during each iteration?

The Iterator and Foreach mediators, seem to iterate according to an XPath expression, which is with respect to the message.

I tried the following

```
<iterate expression="get-property('page_number') &lt; 10" id="iterid" 
xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<target>
    <sequence>
        <log description="log">
            <property name="ola" value="OOOLLLAAA"/>
        </log>
    </sequence>         
</target>
</iterate>
```

IT results in the following error.

```
[2020-01-29 12:46:41,709] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath} - Evaluation of the XPath expression get-property('page_number') < 10 resulted in an error org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: No Such Function get-property
at org.jaxen.SimpleFunctionContext.getFunction(SimpleFunctionContext.java:127)
at org.jaxen.ContextSupport.getFunction(ContextSupport.java:242)
at org.jaxen.Context.getFunction(Context.java:216)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sample While loop implementation.
http://bsenduran.blogspot.com/2017/08/while-loop-in-wso2-esb.html

Comment: I have done an implementation on similar lines. But was wondering if there is a simpler approach to do the same.